# What department does an airline pilot fall under?

Tags: airliner, pilots, student-pilot, airline-pilot, career

On LinkedIn, I saw on the Page for the Harry Reid International Airport there were charts for 346 members, 157 of them working in Operations, 43 for Administrative, 37 for Business Development, 25 for Information Technology, 25 for Engineering, 21 for Customer Success and Support, 12 for Finance, 11 for Military and Protective Services, 11 for Arts and Design, 10 for Accounting, 10 for Media and Communication, 10 for Sales, 9 for Community and Social Services, 7 for Human Resources, and 6 for Legal. I'm wondering which of these would an airline pilot would be categorized as.

Answer (score 17):

Airline pilots do not work for airports, they work for the airline companies that use airports.  They would not appear, or be counted in airport employee rosters or organizational charts.

Answer (score 4):

Airline pilots work for an airlines not airports, but for argument's sake, if an airport authority had pilots on staff flying aircraft owned by the airport authority for some reason, say in a corporate transport role (not aware of any, but possible I suppose), they would be under Operations in the org chart, and under that you would expect see a sub group called Flight Operations where the pilots are listed.  Same as an airline.